# How to create a function that will concatenate any given string with second parameter?

Tags: javascript, string, function, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to create a function that I can reuse with any string, passing a string as a first parameter and concatenating operator to it as I am trying to create a basic calculator and I am working with couple of strings which display different values for operators(e.g. 'x' instead of '*').

```
let evalString = '';
let displayString = '';
let currentNumber = '5';

function concOperator(str, operator) {
  str += currentNumber + ' ' + operator + ' ';
}

concOperator(evalString, '*');
concOperator(displayString, 'x');

console.log(evalString);
console.log(evalString);
```

So I expect the evalString to be "5 * " and displayString to be "5 x " after calling a function, but instead it returns empty strings. How could it be fixed?

Comment: You need to ‘return’ the value. Treat the operation as creating a new str value, rather than modifying the existing one, causing the reference to be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not returning anything in your function and you're not assigning it to your variable. Actually, `str` is in the scope of `concOperator` function.

A way to fix this:

```
let evalString = '';
let displayString = '';
let currentNumber = '5';

function concOperator(str, operator) {
    return `${str} ${currentNumber} ${operator} `;
}

evalString = concOperator(evalString, '*');
displayString = concOperator(displayString, 'x');
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response! That solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't pass strings by reference. Strings and other primitives are passed by value, meaning in the first function call of your code, str is a copy of evalString -- modifying str will not modify evalString. You need to return the concatenated value and assign evalString to this result.

(Related and important note: objects in Javascript, as opposed to primitives, use call-by-sharing. This means when an object is passed as a function parameter, the parameter takes on a copy of the value of the *reference* to the object. In other words, re-assigning the parameter variable won't change the original object, but modifying properties *of* the parameter will affect the original object.)

Answer (score 0):

What I would also try is to append the strings into an array and then join the array into a string, for instance:

```
let evalString = '';
let displayString = '';
let currentNumber = '5';

let test = []

function concOperator(data) {
  test = [...test, data]
}

concOperator('5');
concOperator('x');

concOperator('5');
concOperator('*');

console.log(evalString);
console.log(evalString);

console.log(test.join(' '))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not mutable in JavaScript, `str+=something` is a short form for `str=str+something`, where the right side creates a brand new string, and then it is stored in the local variable, `str`, without altering the original strings (they remain accessible and unchanged outside).
You could [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the result if you want it to be seen from the outside:

```js
function test(a,b){
  console.log("before a,b:",a,b);
  a+=b;
  console.log("after a,b:",a,b);
  return a;
}

var x="x";
var y="y";
var z=test(x,y);
console.log("x,y,z:",x,y,z);
```

So you function could be

```
function concOperator(str, operator) {
  str += currentNumber + ' ' + operator + ' ';
  return str;
}
```

or simply

```
function concOperator(str, operator) {
  return currentNumber + ' ' + operator + ' ';
}
```

and in both cases you would have to store the returned string outside (just happened with `z` above).

Alternatively you can do magic with objects:

```js
function test(a,b){
  console.log("before a:",a);
  console.log("before b:",b);
  a.data+=b;
  console.log("after a:",a);
  console.log("after b:",b);
}

var x={data:"x"};
var y="y";
test(x,y);
console.log("x has changed:",x);
```

Because objects (like `x` in this second snippet) are mutable.

Comment: Thank you! The solution with objects is a little bit confusing for me right now, but it is a great alternative !